# (Altland-Simons) Question about a seemingly additional term in the functional field integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

The following is the part of the book from Atland-Simons. My question is about the additional $-\overline{\psi}^{n+1}\psi_n$ in $(4,27)$ of the book. I understand that the term $\overline{\psi}^{n}\psi_n$ arises due to the overcompleteness relation, i.e. 
$$
\exp\left({-\mbox{$\sum_i$} \bar\psi_i\psi_i}\right)\,,
$$
in $(4.25)$. But why does $-\overline{\psi}^{n+1}\psi_n$ arise?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because
$$
\langle \psi | \hat{H} |\psi'\rangle =\langle \psi | \psi'\rangle\,H(\bar{\psi},\psi')\,,
$$
as written below $(4.28)$. In inserting the resolution of the identity many times you'll get products of
$$
\langle \psi^{n+1} | \hat{H} |\psi^n\rangle = \langle \psi^{n+1} | \psi^n\rangle \,H(\bar{\psi}^{n+1},\psi^n)\,.
$$
The $H(\bar{\psi}^{n+1},\psi^n)$ is there in the exponential, together with the $\bar{\psi}^n \psi^n$ which, as you say, is compensating for the overcompleteness. The remaining piece is
$$
\langle \psi^{n+1} | \psi^n\rangle = \bar{\psi}^{n+1} \psi^n\,,
$$
explaining the extra term at the exponent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I overlooked a simple thing.